# Broken link in Help Center: "bounties" should be "bounty"

Tags: bug, user-interface, help-center

The "[What is reputation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/whats-reputation)" page has a broken link.

> You gain reputation when:  . . .
>
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +1/2 of the bounty amount ([see more details about how bounties work](https://math.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/bounties))

This link in the parentheses directs to a page that does not exist. I believe it should direct to "https://math.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/bounty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed recently, across the network: [404 in Help Center for bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183156/224469)

To beef up this answer (lest it's converted to a comment), I'll point out [help-center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help-center) tag on meta.SO.

To beef it up a little more, I'll ponder aloud whether the existence of [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://math.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/question-bans) means that automatic question bans are now implemented on Math.SE.